# Where did Thanos get his first Infinity Stone?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

Where did Thanos get his first Infinity Stone?

In the beginning of *Avengers: Infinity War*, Thanos had one stone but where did he get it?

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Thor explains it when he's rescued by the Guardians of the Galaxy:

> He got the Power stone last week when he decimated Xandar and he got the Space stone from me when he slaughtered half my people

Thanos attacking Xandar (home planet of the Nova Corps, and where the Guardians left the Orb/Power stone at the end of Guardians of the Galaxy Volume 1) is just not shown in the movie.

Comment: If I know Thanos he did a lot worse than [decimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimation_(Roman_army)). Maybe more like duo-mation ;)

Comment: @josh, I think the word is [`dimidiation`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dimidiation).

Comment: @josh I generally (with great indifference to mathematical accuracy) refer to it as quintuple decimation. Theoretically, Thanos’ equivalent should be ‘secondation’, but that’s not likely to be understood by anyone.

Comment: @josh I think Thor was going for the current definition of decimation ("the killing or destruction of a large proportion of a group or species,") rather than the historical Roman one. :) Even in signal processing "decimation" is often by a factor of 2 (or some power of 2.)

Comment: @reirab but Thor is like well old so he should have definitely used the archaic term :)

Comment: @josh But the Asgardians dealt with the Norse, not the Romans.

Comment: I believe it was shown briefly in the movie.

Comment: @bp. You're probably thinking of Gamora's home planet, not Xandar

Comment: @Draken Possibly but I thought I recalled a 2 second flash-back when they mention him ravaging Xandar.  I'm not about to buy another ticket to check though.  I'm certainly not thinking of the scene of Gamora's home world where his troops divide the populace.

Answer (score 8):

[Dave](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/89075/1190) answered it quite well but here are the director's own words:

> Speaking at Iowa City High, Joe Russo explained that the directors thought it would be "one too many" - that it would cause the writers to "get into a trap," where the film just became repetitive and predictable. Given Guardians of the Galaxy had clearly established where the Power Stone was, it was "easy to deal with it off screen." - [businessinsider](https://www.businessinsider.com/avengers-infinity-war-directors-answer-movie-questions-2018-5?IR=T#why-didnt-we-see-thanos-acquire-the-power-stone-2)

So it just happens off-screen to avoid film looking repetitive.

Comment: That was probably a good call... the mystery of how he got the power stone at all, vs an ever powerful Thanos consistently winning virtually every major engagement.